# Error Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Tags: django-views

I keep getting this error
Reverse for 'password_reset_done' not found. 'password_reset_done' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
i am trying to use the default view from
from django.contrib.auth.views

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from accounts import views 
from django.contrib.auth.views import (login, 
logout, 
password_reset, 
password_reset_done, 
password_reset_confirm, 
) 


urlpatterns =[ 
url(r'^$', views.cover, name='cover'), 
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name = 'home'), 
url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name':'accounts/login.html'}, name ="login"), 
url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name':'accounts/logout.html'}, name = "logout"), # views define a link to connecct this to views then to template 
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"), 
url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'), 
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'), 
url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'), 
url(r'^reset-password/$', password_reset, name= 'password_reset'), 
url(r'^reset-password/done/$', password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'), 
url(r'^reset-password/confirm/$', password_reset_confirm, name='password_reset_confirm') 
]
```

Please anybody help me out... i have check all... but couldnt find the fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this code and this seems to work.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from accounts import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import  (login, 
                                    logout,     
                                    password_reset, 
                                    password_reset_done,
                                    password_reset_confirm, 
                                )
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns =[
    url(r'^$', views.cover, name='cover'), 
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name':'accounts/login.html'}, name ="login"), 
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name':'accounts/logout.html'}, name = "logout"),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,{'email_template_name':'accounts/registration/password_reset_email.html',
                                                    'subject_template_name':'accounts/registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                                                    'post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_done',
                                                    'from_email':'accounts@django.com',
                                                    },name='password_reset'),

    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'accounts/registration/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'),
```

in above code accounts in myapp name. where you can put your own apps name
This is for Django 1.11

Answer (score 23):

it'll work if you just use `path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))` in your main `urls.py` not the one in your `app_name`.

Comment: This really fixed my issue

Answer (score 8):

plz try this 
be carefull to watch for some errors like not adding the $ at the end of some urls or maybe adding it. also pay attention to where success_url is given because the internal code uses it and is lost without it.

here in this code the application that I chose to manage users is called accounts, you can call yours anything.

the templates should be put inside a directory that is recognized by django otherwise it won't find them here is the code for settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

and here is the full urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from accounts.views import signup

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'signup/$', signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html')),
    url(r'logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='logout.html')),
    url(r'password_change/$',auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='password_change.html',success_url='/accounts/password_change_done')),
    url(r'password_change_done/',auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_change_done.html')),
    url(r'password_reset/$',auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='password_reset.html',email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt',success_url='/accounts/password_reset_done/',from_email='support@yoursite.ma')),
    url(r'password_reset_done/',auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_done.html')),
    url(r'password_reset_confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_confirm.html',success_url='/accounts/password_reset_complete/')),
    url(r'password_reset_complete/',auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='password_reset_complete.html')),
]
```

Comment: Do we need to mention the success url explicitly in  password_reset? I am using django 2.2. In doc its given that it should automatically go to success url

Comment: Way to go to the top

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but solved it by adding the success_url parameter in PasswordResetView :

Add *success_url* parameter of Class Based View [PasswordResetView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView). This will replace default route of password_reset_done

```
url(r'^reset/$',PasswordResetView.as_view(
    template_name='password_reset.html',
    email_template_name='password_reset_email.html',
    subject_template_name='password_reset_subject.txt',
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')
    ...
    ...
),name='password_reset'),
```

Comment: I believe this is the best answer for current releases of Django. I would add that there are two default auth views in Django which will break when using your own namespace. The `PasswordResetView` mentioned here and the `PasswordResetConfirmView`. In the latter case, you should also provide the `success_url` override pointing to your `password_reset_complete` path.

Answer (score 2):

These occurs when Django is updated from 1.xx to 2.xx (well, as in my own case).

This is my solution. I fixed it by including a dictionary with key "**post_change_redirect**" with it's value pointing to the `password_change_done` url. For password resetting use `post_rest_redirect`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as v
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = 
......
    url(r"password-change/$", v.password_change, {"post_change_redirect":"account:password_change_done"}, name="password_change")
.........

]
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular error may also occur when Django was upgraded from version 1.xx to version 2.xx

To fix this:

1. Add this line in *main* url.py:

   ```
   url(r'^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
   ```
2. And then replace functions with classes in 'your_app/urls.py'. E.g.

   ```
   password_reset => PasswordResetView.as_view()
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   url(r'^reset-password/$', PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
   url(r'^reset-password/done/$', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),

   url(r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$', PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),

   url(r'^reset-password/complete/$', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import, app_name, some templates and template routes.

Change your code for this:

```
from django.conf.urls import url 
from accounts import views 
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views 

app_name = 'accounts' # Django 2.0+, if not add namespace = 'accounts' on the urls.py where you are including this set of urls.

urlpatterns =[ 
url(r'^$', views.cover, name='cover'), 
url(r'^home/$', views.home, name = 'home'), 
url(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name':'accounts/login.html'}, name ="login"), 
url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'template_name':'accounts/logout.html'}, name = "logout"),
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name="register"), 
url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'), 
url(r'^profile/edit/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'), 
url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'), 
url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset,{'email_template_name':'registration/password_reset_email.html',
                                                    'subject_template_name':'registration/password_reset_subject.txt',
                                                    'post_reset_redirect':'accounts:password_reset_done',
                                                    'from_email':'accounts@django.com', # Yours
                                                    },name='password_reset'),

url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, {'template_name': 'registration/password_reset_done.html'}, name='password_reset_done'), 
]
```

Be sure in your folder "accounts" you have: /templates/registration/*.html with all your templates

Answer (score 0):

For me the key info that was missing was the reverse resolve needing the name attribute set on the url entry!

```
    path(
    'password_change/done/',
    auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='SyllabusTrackerApp/change-password-done.html'),
    name="password_change_done"
),
```

The `app_name` namespace wasn't set either, but those weren't used in my setup for simplicity, so I could ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution which I've found is as below, this may help.
for password reset link first import in urls.py file of your app.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

then add the following path in your app urls.py file

```
path('password_reset', auth_views.PasswordResetView, name='password_reset'),
```

finally you can use it in your HTML pages as below

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:password_reset'%}" class="float-end">
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, I just added this to my main project url:

```
path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
```

Works like magic.

Comment: This is just adding the URLs from Django's auth app so it resolves with its default code. If you are trying to reuse the views from a different app, you have to tune them as per David's answer.